# Decoding URL of Dynamically Generated page in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have Ecommerce website. A page where all products are listed (Used ListView Control). I have created one more page for one single product details(original name as DynamicPage) but when it loads it  replaces it's name in url as product name. Till here all is fine but here URL comes like this

`http://localhost:57265/OTTALINE%20Water%20Resistant%20Bluetooth%20Speakers.aspx`

I want like this

```
http://localhost:57265/OTTALINE-Water-Resistant-Bluetooth-Speakers
```

Can anyone help me?

DynamicPage Load function

```
Private Sub PopulatePage()
        Dim pageName As String = Me.Page.RouteData.Values("product_name").ToString()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = @PageName"
        Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(conString)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageName", pageName)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                            productName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("product_name").ToString()
                            sku.Text = dt.Rows(0)("sku").ToString()
                            shortIntro.Text = dt.Rows(0)("short_brief").ToString()
                            stock.Text = dt.Rows(0)("stock_status").ToString()
                            moq.Text = dt.Rows(0)("moq").ToString()
                            shipDays.Text = dt.Rows(0)("delivery_time").ToString()
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()

Comment: @Sami Is this code need to be used on PageLoad?

Comment: How is page is invoked , on a click of a hyperlink ?

Comment: @Sami I think so. There are 2 pages one is shop.aspx in which Listview Control where all products listed. On click of any product it's linked with this page(DynamicPage.aspx)

Comment: @Sami at least you could reply

Comment: As on click of Product a new page is generated, so let me investigate more to find solution. Simply putting  or UrlEncode HtmlEncodeUrlEncodeperlink may not fix the issue. I reckon huge stackoverflow community would find something for this problem.